# Mosca sends multiple messages continously

Tags: node.js, mosca

I have setup a node js server with Mosca running on it. Clients are able to connect to the Mosca server and publish a message. I need to the send an acknowledgment in the form of a message(subscribed to some topic) back to the client.

The below code sends multiple messages continuously once the message is published by the client. Am I missing anything?

```
 var settings = {
    port: 1882,
    backend: ascoltatore
 };

 var message = {
   topic: 'crofters',
   payload: 'OK', // or a Buffer
   qos: 2

 };

 var server = new mosca.Server(settings);

 server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
       console.log('client connected', client.id);


   });

   // fired when a message is received
server.on('published', function(packet, client ) {


    var packet_payload = packet.payload;
    packet_payload = packet_payload.toString();
    console.log('Published', packet_payload);

    server.publish(message, function() {
        console.log('done!');
    });


});

server.on('ready', setup);

function setup() {
   console.log('Mosca server is up and running');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event listener `server.on('published', function(packet, client){...}` listens to every publishing events, including the server's.

What is happening is that when you use `server.publish(message, function(){...})` inside that listener it triggers another **published** event, which is immediately caught by the listener.

It never stops publishing because it never stops catching its own events.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing similar issues. If you notice, Mosca has only QoS 0 and Qos 1

So I suppose the broker tries to send the same message more than once "at least once" until it receives some acknowledgement from a client. Check this [document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718101) out